# Javascript ajax code syntax

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax

What's wrong with my syntax? I got an eror in the Firefox debug console. I'm using .NET MVC btw.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(':submit').on('click', function () {
            var button = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("Trelon"))", 
                data: { @Model.Defeli : $(this).val()}, 
                dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            })
            .done(function (data) { 
                $('#myTextDiv').html(''); 
                $('#myTextDiv').append('Test');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

This mentions the 3 line in the above sample:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id 3:61:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("Trelon"))", 
        data: { @Model.Defeli : $(this).val()}, 
        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    })
```

Removing the comma at the end helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@(Url.RouteUrl('Trelon'))",
    data: {@Model.Defeli : $(this).val()}, 
    dataType: 'json', 
})
```

Comment: Too many characters in character literal. I think that's also bad syntax;

Comment: {
    url: "@(Url.RouteUrl('Trelon'))",
    data: {@Model.Defeli : $(this).val()}, 
    dataType: 'json', 
}

Comment: `$(this).val()` referring to `whome` and what is `value` of `@Model.Defeli` try `value of @Model.Defeli `

Comment: the val refers to a button value, @Model.Defeli is a string

Answer (score 0):

try `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` if try giving hard value for `url and data`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("Trelon"))",
  data: {@Model.Defeli : $(this).val()}, 
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

If `@Model.Defeli` has special characters or is not a string, `data` won't be a valid JSON

Comment: It is a List of string. Some have special characters though.

Comment: But you're using it as a JSON attribute, not as a value. The error has to be  that. you could use `data: { myList: @Model.Defeli  }`, where myList is the parameter name you would expect in your controller action, and it can be a `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Can you post the rendered JS script?